# what's the easiest way to match up /dev/sdx with a device mounted in /media?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, dev

I can never remember which device is what so when it comes to partitioning, etc. I'm afraid of messing up the wrong drive. Automounted devices like external drives don't seem to turn up in fstab. So each time I run into this I google and each time I seem to use a different method.

What's the most straightforward way to match up what device under /media/ is in /dev/ independent of linux distribution? (And I'm aware /media/ is probably a distro-dependent variable itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the `mount`program without arguments from the command line. It'll show you mount points and corresponding devices.